# using switch to check market and prefix with correct currency symbol

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hey I have a report where I have order value in one of the columns. I also have a market parameter which has UK and US. What I want to be able to do is to use switch to check which market code is passed and give the respected currency symbol prefixed.

E.g. See image below

[image]

I am clueless how to do this based on what is passed onto the parameter.

Comment: Are US and UK the only options you will ever have for markets, or will that grow in the future?

Comment: In the format property you can use =IIF(Parameters!Country.Value="UK","£ #,##0", "$ #,##0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions.

If you only have the 2 markets:

```
=Format(Fields!Money.Value, IIf(Parameters!Market.Value = "US", "$#.##", "£#.##"))
```

If you will have more markets in the future, you want to use switch so you can add more easily.

```
=Format(Fields!Money.Value, Switch(Parameters!Market.Value = "US","$#.##",Parameters!Market.Value = "UK","£#.##", etc...)
```

Remove the `.##` if you do not want the values after the decimal.

Comment: thanks. And I just remembered. How can I add the comma between the thousand values? I forgot to add that in the question

Comment: Excellent. You are now a currency formatting expert. Congrats! :)

Comment: lol cheers. These fields arn't divisible though because of the currency symbol. Why is that? i have a column which divides this field to the previous but it now shows error :'(

Comment: The formatting turns them into a string. You have to keep them as numbers if you want to perform any calculations on them in the report. You can do that in the expressions, just leave out the format.